# Merging 2 files with the head and tail utilities in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, head, tail

My two input files are as follows:

new

```
111
222
333
```

old

```
555
666
```

I want to merge them to get the following output

```
111
555
222
666
333
```

This is what I've tried so far

```
i=1
while read line
do
   head -$i $1 | tail -1
   head -$i $2 | tail -1 
   i=$(($i+1));
done < $1
```

This is the output I receive

```
111
555
222
666
333
666
```

How do I prevent it from taking the last line in 'old' twice? It should also be able to merge the two files if the second file is larger than the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use paste:

```
paste -d"\n" /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the OP actually wanted to do `head` and `tail` just for experimentation, here's a modification of his code:

```
lenA=`wc -l $1 | awk '{print $1}'`
lenB=`wc -l $2 | awk '{print $1}'`

i=1
while read line
do
   tail -$(($lenA - $i + 1 >= 0?$lenA - $i + 1:0)) $1 | head -1
   tail -$(($lenB - $i + 1 >= 0?$lenB - $i + 1:0)) $2 | head -1
   i=$(($i+1));
done < $1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `bash` only:

```
while true; do    
    read -r newline
    read -r oldline <&3
    if [[ -z "$newline" && -z "$oldline" ]]; then 
        break;
    fi
    if [[ ! -z "$newline" ]]; then 
        echo "$newline"
    fi
    if [[ ! -z "$oldline" ]]; then
        echo "$oldline"
    fi
done <new 3<old
```

**Output:**

```
111
555
222
666
333
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BASH `read` loop on one file and pass the increment variable to `awk` to get the same line number from the other file so you can print them in the order you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while read line; do
    echo $line
    awk -v i=$i 'NR==i' $2
    ((i++))
done < $1
```